# How to convert one date string into another format in objective C

Tags: ios4

I am reading a date field from database as a string type, Now I want to convert that date string to another format but while using NSDateFormatter dateFromString method returns nil.

please help me in identifying date format while reading from database

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell, but here is a very simple use of the date formatter that I use to read a date like 2012-05-17 11:30:00. Just change the string based on your date format and it should work.

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:string];
[inputFormatter release];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my problem is with the setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". I do not know which date format comes from the database.

Comment: Can you log it once and assume that it will never change? An other method, not really pretty but safer if the format changes, is to make a method that will try each format one after the other if it was not the correct format (the date returned is nil)

Comment: can you please post a link with all possible date formats supported in iphone